# create a new module in odoo 10

Tags: python, module, odoo, view

I am new in odoo I have to modify a module so I would like to be attending.
How do the methods in the model called (e.g. in the view when I click a button)?
I understand that methods like calculated fields are called automatically, but what about other methods?

Comment: A first starting point to look for information is the [Odoo doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/index.html) and for your question maybe [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/views.html#reference-views-list-button)

Comment: CDspace Thank you for your answer the link you gave me corresponds well to my question. However you have an idea how to customize the POS module. For example I opened the folder js of the module but I do not understand the role of the files that exist in.